# Find norm of bounded linear operator on $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:\ell^2\rightarrow\ell^2$ be the operator defined by 
$$
T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots )=(0,2x_1,x_2,2x_3,x_4,\ldots )
$$

I want to show that $\|T\|=2$.

I have shown that $\|Tx\|\leq2\|x\|$ I'm not sure which sequence $x$ gives $\|Tx\|=2\|x\|$. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Try a sequence where $x_i = 0$ for even $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are left with showing $\|T\|\ge 2$. Choose $x=(1,0,0,\ldots)\in l^2$, then $\|x\|_{l^2}=1$ and 
$$ \|T\|\ge\frac{\|Tx\|_{l^2}}{\|x\|_{l^2}} = \|Tx\|_{l^2} = \left(|2|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2.$$